# Android AutoCompleteTextView displays suggestions after unrelated button is clicked

Tags: android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am having an issue where my `AutoCompleteTextView` is showing its suggestions if keyboard focus is in the ACTV and a button in the activity is clicked.  The best I can seem to do is call `.dismissDropDown()` after it appears, but that seems sloppy. How can I keep it from appearing in the first place when the button is clicked?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you reword it please.

Comment: Andrei is right, please rephrase your question because the actual problem is unclear. What does ACTV mean? How does *the button* relate to the dropdown and what is it's use?

Comment: I'm not sure how to better describe it.  I have a simple ACTV implemented as in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html).  When I click an unrelated button in the activity, and the insertion caret is in the ACTV, then the whole list of auto-completes is displayed.  Obviously, I don't need the list of completions displayed at that point.

Comment: On further investigation, this is happening because I am modifying the `ArrayAdapter<String>` (to include the most recent input in the autocomplete list) in the button click code.  If I take out the `.insert()` call, then the autocomplete list does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, this was due to me adding an element to the `ArrayAdapter` adapter of the ACTV. I just went ahead and added the new string to the original `ArrayList` used for initially creating the `ArrayAdapter`, then created a completely new `AA` and set that as the ACTV's adapter.  That method of dynamic updating fixed the problem of the autocomplete list appearing when it wasn't supposed to.